# Скачать файл mp4 по ссылке java

Tags: java, download, mp4

Пытаюсь написать программу, которая будет скачивать файл mp4 с удаленного ресурса по ссылке, однако получаю exception:

> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

```
OutputStream outStream = null;
InputStream is = null;
HttpURLConnection conn;
try {
    URL url;
    byte[] buf;
    int byteRead, byteWritten = 0;
    url = new URL(getFinalLocation("https://cdn-1.watchenga.tv/movies/the-cabin-in-the-woods/original_360.mp4"));
    outStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("test.mp4"));

    conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    is = conn.getInputStream();
    buf = new byte[1024];
    while ((byteRead = is.read(buf)) != -1) {
        outStream.write(buf, 0, byteRead);
        byteWritten += byteRead;
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {

    //   is.close();
    //    outStream.close();

}
```

Comment: Попробуйте `http`, а не `https`. Исходя из ошибки он не может найти сертификат.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12146838/4444092

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это часто означает, что веб-сервер или URL-адрес, к которому вы подключаетесь, не имеют действительного сертификата от уполномоченного центра сертификации.
В таком случае можно импортировать сертификат сервера и установить его в хранилище ключей JDK. 
Введите URL-адрес в браузер, сохраните сертификат на жесткий диск (в firefox - в адресной строке ЛКМ на значок "показать информацию о сайте" - "показать информацию о соединении" - "подробнее" - "защита" - "просмотреть сертификат" - "подробности" - "экспортировать").

После этого вы можете импортировать его в хранилище ключей JDK, используя инструмент keytool, находящийся по адресу ...\Java\jdk{version}\bin.
Переместите сертификат в ....\Java\jdk{version}\bin\, запустите из этой папки командную строку с правами администратора, и выполните следующую команду:
keytool -import -trustcacerts -keystore cacerts -storepass changeit -noprompt -alias **addSert** -file **filename**.cer, заменив addSert(не обязательно) на любое другое незанятое имя и filename на имя сохраненного сертификата. 
После успешного выполнения должно появиться сообщение
**Certificate was added to keystore**, после которого можно удалить сертификат из папки ....\Java\jdk{version}\bin\